# Need to display alt text from child image

Tags: jquery

This works...

```
$('.tubepress_thumb img').mouseenter(
function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','.8');
    var a = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="tp_title">' + a + '</div>');
});
```

But flickers b/c the appended div covers the image.

So I'm trying to target the containing element of both the img and the appended div and do this...

```
$('.tubepress_thumb').mouseenter(
function(){
    $(this).children('img').css('opacity','.8');
    var a = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');
    $(this).append('<div class="tp_title">' + a + '</div>');
});
```

But instead of the alt text, I get 'undefined.'

I've check and confirmed in several posts that $(this).children('img').attr('alt'); is correct, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: a jsfiddle might be a good idea

Comment: You're missing that the selector returns (potentially) multiple elements; whereas you want only one.

Comment: maybe there is no `alt`

Comment: Is the `<img>` element an immediate child of the `.tubepress_thumb` element? Try `$(this).find('img')` instead of `$(this).children('img')`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks, find() did it. David Thomas: I assumed that since there was only one child image, it would work. My bad. PedroEstrada: Good reminder! Hoff: thanks for reminding me re:jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If the `<img>` element isn't an immediate child of the `.tubepress_thumb` element, you'll need to use [`$(this).find('img')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`$(this).children('img')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find it.